# How to match using Regex till the invalid response (C#)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to write a regex that matches the following string till `E 1 ERRORWARNING SET \n`, (till the end of invalid response). `M 1 CSD ...` are valid response strings.

##### Scenario #1

```
"M 1 CSD 382 01 44 2B 54 36 7B 22 6A \n" +
"M 1 CSD 382 00 73 6F 6E 72 70 63 22 \n" +
"R OK \n" +                   // This could be any string not matching the pattern M 1 CSD ...
"E 1 ERRORWARNING SET \n" +   // This could be any string not matching the pattern M 1 CSD ...
"M 1 CSD 382 00 3A 22 32 2E 30 22 2C \n" +
```

##### Scenario #2

```
"R OK \n" +                   // This could be any string not matching the pattern M 1 CSD ...
"E 1 ERRORWARNING SET \n" +   // This could be any string not matching the pattern M 1 CSD ...
"M 1 CSD 382 00 3A 22 32 2E 30 22 2C \n" +
```

I know I can write something like `(M 1 CSD (?:.{3}) (?:.{2}\s)+\n)*` to match the `M 1 CSD` pattern but not sure how to match the invalid response. The best I am able to do is
`(M 1 CSD (?:.{3}) (?:.{2}\s)+\r\n)*([^M].*\r\n)*`. But what happens if the invalid response starts with M?

Off course it is possible that there is no invalid response, then the regex needs to match till the end, i.e till `M 1 CSD 382 02 30 33 22 7D 7D \n`

```
"M 1 CSD 382 01 44 2B 54 36 7B 22 6A \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 73 6F 6E 72 70 63 22 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 3A 22 32 2E 30 22 2C \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 22 69 64 22 3A 30 2C \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 22 72 65 73 75 6C 74 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 22 3A 7B 22 53 65 72 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 69 61 6C 4E 75 6D 62 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 65 72 22 3A 22 32 32 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 00 32 30 31 31 34 32 35 \n"
"M 1 CSD 382 02 30 33 22 7D 7D \n"
```

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat matching all lines that do not have `ERRORWARNING SET` the invalid response starts with `M`

```
^(?![\w ]* ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n).+(?:\r?\n(?![\w ]* ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n).+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![\w ]* ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n)` Assert that the string does not start with ERRORWARNING SET preceded by optional word chars and spaces
- `.+` Match the whole line with at least a single char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?![\w ]* ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n)` Assert that the next line does not start with ERRORWARNING SET preceded by optional word chars and spaces
  - `.+` Match the whole line with at least a single char
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%5b%5cw+%5d*+ERRORWARNING+SET+%5cr%3f%5cn%29.%2b%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5b%5cw+%5d*+ERRORWARNING+SET+%5cr%3f%5cn%29.%2b%29*&i=M+1+CSD+382+01+44+2B+54+36+7B+22+6A+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+73+6F+6E+72+70+63+22+%0d%0aR+OK+%0d%0aM+1+ERRORWARNING+SET+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+3A+22+32+2E+30+22+2C+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+01+44+2B+54+36+7B+22+6A+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+73+6F+6E+72+70+63+22+%0d%0aR+OK+%0d%0aE+1+ERRORWARNING+SET+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+3A+22+32+2E+30+22+2C+%0d%0a%0d%0aR+OK+%0d%0aE+1+ERRORWARNING+SET+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+3A+22+32+2E+30+22+2C+%0d%0a%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+01+44+2B+54+36+7B+22+6A+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+73+6F+6E+72+70+63+22+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+3A+22+32+2E+30+22+2C+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+22+69+64+22+3A+30+2C+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+22+72+65+73+75+6C+74+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+22+3A+7B+22+53+65+72+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+69+61+6C+4E+75+6D+62+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+65+72+22+3A+22+32+32+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+00+32+30+31+31+34+32+35+%0d%0aM+1+CSD+382+02+30+33+22+7D+7D+&o=m)

---

Or a bit more strict to test that the string does not start with a single char A-Z followed by 1 and then ERRORWARNING SET

```
^(?![A-Z] 1 ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n).+(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z] 1 ERRORWARNING SET \r?\n).+)*
```